# DataGridView Printing

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview, export

How do I print specified rows  out to a file from a DataGridView?
Also how can I print out certain columns?

### This is what I have been trying to work with.. but it is not working..:

```
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
            saveFile1.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFile1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile1.FileName);

                List<string> theList = new List<string>();

                foreach (var line in theFinalDGV.Rows)
                {
                    if (line.ToString().Contains("FUJI"))
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(line + "\n");
                }
            }
    }
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: do you only want the conent of the row ('Value' 'Value' )or also the columnname('Coulmnname':'Value','Coulmnname':'Value')?

Comment: @wowa: just the content.

Comment: have a look at the second example in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridViewRow.ToString() only gives you the typename back, not the row content. You can use this extender to get the rowcontent ('ColumnName'):

```
public static class Extender {
    public static string RowToString(this DataGridViewRow dgvr) {
        string output = "";

        DataGridView dgv = dgvr.DataGridView;

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvr.Cells) {

            DataGridViewColumn col = cell.OwningColumn;
            output += col.HeaderText + ":" + cell.Value.ToString() + ((dgv.Columns.IndexOf(col) < dgv.Columns.Count - 1) ? ", " : "");
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

if you only want the content of the row without the coulmn-headername use this (space separated):

```
public static class Extender {
    public static string RowToString(this DataGridViewRow dgvr) {
        string output = "";

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvr.Cells) {
            output += cell.Value.ToString() + " ";
        }

        return output.TrimEnd();
    }
}
```

your code will look like this:

```
class YourClass
{
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
            saveFile1.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFile1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile1.FileName);

                List<string> theList = new List<string>();

                foreach (var line in theFinalDGV.Rows)
                {
                    string linecontent = line.RowToString();
                    if (linecontent.Contains("FUJI"))
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(linecontent + "\n");
                }
            }
    }
}

public static class Extender {
    public static string RowToString(this DataGridViewRow dgvr) {
        string output = "";

        DataGridView dgv = dgvr.DataGridView;

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvr.Cells) {

            DataGridViewColumn col = cell.OwningColumn;
            output += col.HeaderText + ":" + cell.Value.ToString() + ((dgv.Columns.IndexOf(col) < dgv.Columns.Count - 1) ? ", " : "");
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```